# JavaScript Undefined Error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this JavaScript error with IE explorer:

> 'Slideshow is undefined'

The error points to this bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new SlideShow('listOfImages');
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `SlideShow` defined?

Comment: `Slideshow`, or `SlideShow`? In JavaScript case is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you didn't include the required javascripts files for mootools

http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/

http://code.google.com/p/slideshow/

for example, include mootools, and slideshow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

SlideShow is a name of an object constructor. It has to be defined prior to its use in the script tag either in the embedded script or in a file loaded by the  tag